# SMS sent using AWS SNS fails

Tags: amazon-sns

I am trying to send an SMS using AWS SNS through the CLI using the following command

`aws sns publish --phone-number +918XXXXXXXX3 --message foo`

I get a message-id as a response like the following

```
{
   "MessageId": "7b80cabd-70ca-56b1-8dba-9d3ab28e5d5d" 
}
```

After some time when I check cloud watch logs for SNS I get the below-mentioned error

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "7b80cabd-70ca-56b1-8dba-9d3ab28e5d5d",
        "timestamp": "2020-07-14 12:40:48.181"
    },
    "delivery": {
        "destination": "+918XXXXXXXX3",
        "smsType": "Transactional",
        "providerResponse": "Internal Error",
        "dwellTimeMs": 70
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
}
```

Comment: I suspect you'll have to ask AWS Support on this one.

Comment: yeah, I was trying to contact. unfortunately, I can't find a way to contact AWS Support unless I get some support package.

Comment: There's no contract, and it's billed by time used, so you can add the Developer tier support ($29/month) and cancel when you've got your answer.

Comment: I found the below sentence mentioned on the pricing page of support plans
*** Plans are subject to a 30-day minimum term.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/plans/

Answer (score 0):

I had raised a support request for this issue with AWS and they have responded. Here is the complete response.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Frustrating there's not a better error message in that scenario.

Comment: Take a look here https://aws.amazon.com/pt/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sns-sms-spending-limit-increase/ , you need to request a spending limit increase. I'm getting in same issue.